# validating linux users from java

Tags: java, linux, spring, jsch

I have created users and two groups(say group1 and group2) in AWS ec2 server. users belong to group one can perform read,write and execute operations and same for users belong to group2. currently, I am developing an application called report management system using Java Jsch library. users can make changes and upload the file to the server but before performing file operations they should be validated. I have users and groups in aws server and I want to validate particular user and associated group(users belong to group1 can make changes only on particular folder) before allowing them to make changes. Is there anyway to validate linux users and groups from java?

Comment: What do xou mean with validating users/groups? Should the users be able to log in with their linux credentials in your application? How is that related to jsch?

Comment: Hi dan, basically I'm using Jsch for file transfering to server. users are created in linux server but they usually upload files through application not through server. since they are uploading from application there should be validation before performing any file operations. is there anyway that we can validate from application?

Comment: I see. I thought your application runs on the linux server.

Comment: If you have established an SSH session, you could try [finding out the groups with `id`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252981/378034) or you manage file access with linux permisdions and check if accessing the file failed with jsch.